# Updating a specifc entry using Protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a list of objects (let's say `class AccessLevel`) that is being serialized using Protofbuf-Net.

The objects are not fixed-sized, is it possible to update a single object in the serialized file (based on index) without rewriting the whole file?

Comment: Ah, how much work are you willing to make for that? The answer is "yes, it is possible" but I would say it is likely a LOT more complicated than would be reasonable. You also may end up rewriting MOST of the file except some initial bytes (so you technically do not the WHOLE file).

Comment: Ummmm... A bit disappointing. The cost of rewriting the file is not great, so I guess I'll just do that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the change makes it smaller or doesn't impact the size: probably, but there is nothing in the library to help you do this, as it is not a supported scenario. For same-length: just overwrite. Of course, knowing the length in advance is a trick :)

At the protocol level, when reducing size: you could pad data out by faking an unused field, or by using suboptimal varint encoding of existing fields (spare bytes with nothing except the continuation bit).

If it gets bigger: no amount of trickery is going to save you from having to rework the entire file.

These are both theoretical. A more practical answer is provably: no.